# define types for url query-parameters in aws api-gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Is there a way to actually define the type of a query-parameter? Atm, I can only define the name and if the parameter is required:

[image]

f.e. I would like to define arrays or numbers as query-paramters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multivalued parameter for array

```
     GET resource?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

If you share your usecase why you need number or bigdecimal  or int will help you to find solution.

Comment: I know that this will work. I want to define the explicit types (number, string[]) etc that I can use it in my generated code later.